# Could the weather be created without magic?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, climate, weather

Aclime is a strange planet. It is Earth-like, with seas and land, but for some reason, there's no weather: more specifically, a sort of supernatural force exist, that pushes against any flow, thus causing it to decay into non-flow. To keep the planet lush and living, a race of 1ft tall, slender humanoids known as fairies have taken up the duties of creating weather, with wind, clouds, and rain, in the manner of Earth. But, there is one caveat: the fairies have no magic, nor any sort of supernatural power. Furthermore, their technology is quite poor, on par with Earth in 1850.

Could these fairies pull off this great feat, or is Aclime doomed to desertification?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing more about the "some reason" that there is no weather.  Is there no sun?  Is the whole thing a simulation?  If the reason is a race of 8 inch tall bogles preventing weather then the 1 ft tall fairies could whup on them and let the weather happen  But more complicated reasons would require more complicated solutions.

Comment: So let me get this straight. There magically is no weather, but the elves create weather that should be there in the first place (only without using magic)? There would be weather without the magic (that's physics) so any efforts the elves use are doomed to fail unless we understand what is blocking weather. Who knows? Maybe the elves are anti-magical, and their physical presence allows the weather to happen like it physically should. So why is there no weather?

Comment: Aclime's lack of weather is a supernatural effect that prevents evaporation, fluid motion, and other effects that cause weather, and dampens it when it is caused by an outside influence

Comment: So, to clarify, you wish an explanation as to how to counteract a supernatural effect of undefined nature, by the behaviour of fairies who possess no supernatural or anything but the most basic scientific abilities?

Comment: With no fluid motion, the faeries would die, as life forms are reliant on fluid moving. If you magically block key biological processes, the fairies are not gonna be able to do much.

Comment: @NepeneNep The force is not strong enough to overcome the fairies biological processes

Comment: Edward Lorenz' [butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) could create a tornado several weeks later. Surely, whatever butterflies can, fairies can too!

Comment: It already has weather, it's just monotonous. What is needed is variable weather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No chance to create the weather as we know it**

These fairies are not using any magic or machines to do their work. Looks like they have to use their own muscle power, maybe accompanied by primitive hydro turbines or steam engines to do the job.

On the Earth, total wind power potential is estimated at about 100 TW, which translates to almost 900 PWh on the annual basis. This is only wind, and only in the low atmosphere. By comparison, total electricity generation today is less than 30 PWh, or about 30 times lower.

And wind is only one of the number of atmospheric phenomena which all involve power. Even today, the entire human-created infrastructure comprises only a small fraction of the total weather energy. In 1850, this fraction was much lower. Fairies could work themselves to total exhaustion, but without magic they would be helpless.

Answer (score 1):

### Plants can modify the weather.

See [this article](https://earth.stanford.edu/news/know-your-planet-how-do-plants-affect-weather) for more details. Plants draw moisture from the ground, reflect sunlight.

> “I was personally impressed with how strong these feedbacks were in some of the localized regions,” said co-author Alexandra Konings, an assistant professor of Earth System Science in Stanford’s School of Earth, Energy & Environmental Sciences. “Thirty percent might not sound like a lot, but it could mean potentially significant gains in our ability to make sub-seasonal and seasonal predictions.”

> The researchers found that substantial vegetation-precipitation feedback loops often occur in semi-arid or monsoonal regions, in effect hotspots that are transitional between energy and water limitation. In addition, strong biosphere-radiation feedbacks are often present in several moderately wet regions, for instance in the Eastern U.S. and in the Mediterranean, where precipitation and radiation increase vegetation growth. Vegetation growth enhances heat transfer and increases the height of the Earth’s boundary layer, the lowest part of the atmosphere that is highly responsive to surface radiation. This increase in turn affects cloudiness and surface radiation.

They would plant appropriate crops in lots of places to help transform the land. This would presumably be enough to overcome the supernatural barriers that prevent the world from improving, which were designed to be powerful enough to handle nature, not a race of faeries who artificially make lots of trees to make more clouds.

As you said, magic can't overcome biology, and so presumably the plants can overcome the magic as well.

Comment: They said weather doesn't work. They didn't indicate all processes don't work. Presumably the magic has limits, which per my answer, happens to be plants which can break those limits.

Comment: I added an edit on this. Fairy biology can overcome the magic, so presumably plants can as well.